# CSS: column loads squished in internet explorder

Tags: css, internet-explorer

my site http://action.news loads fine in chrome/firefox .
However, on internet explorer, the right div column loads all stuck together

but not the main page only when you read an article

i converted my site from tables/2000s era to mobile friendly

here is a sample article

```
http://action.news/westnetnews.php?article=Romanian-born%20Actress%20Makes%20Debut%20on%20Canadian%20Television%20Series
```

here is what it looks like in IE

[image]

Comment: It would be better if you posted the offending CSS here.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a css flexbox layout. There is only partial suport in IE11 for flexbox. See https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox for details of feature compatibility.

IE11 was released in 2013. You'll need to decide if compatibility is worth changing from flex to something that works in IE.

Comment: well in 2013 it did that and even firefox 2018 does that sometimes

Comment: So, are you actually looking for an answer to a problem in Firefox? Is that just the sidebar full of adds that gets squished?